# How to make a Fragment callback from within a ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, listadapter

In my Android app I've created a list of options in a fragment using a custom ListAdapter (extending BaseAdapter). When a user clicks on one of the options it needs to switch the fragment in the activity for another fragment. From within the fragment I can do the following to switch the fragment:

```
callbacks.switchNewScreen();
```

I don't have any idea though, how I can use this same thing from within the listadapter.

Furthermore, the list is created from a string-array:

```
<string-array name="the_list">
    <item>Option one</item>
    <item>The second option</item>
    <item>And yet another option</item>
</string-array>
```

I do this because I want to be able to translate them into other languages in the future. The problem is now that even if I get to the other fragment, how do I know which option was pressed?

Comment: you can pass the context to the constructor of adapter. then use a interface as a call back to the activity. you can pass the index of click ie position from getView

Comment: can you post your code of listactivity and the callbacks

Comment: @Raghunandan - Thanks for the tip. I just wonder; how would "use an interface as a call back to the activity"? I already do that from within the fragment, but I don't know how to extend callback to the adapter? Any tips?

Comment: show the code how you do it fragment and the adapter code.